# How to use variable in field Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the variable `@lang`, which will change every time when user clicks on flag by the session. The value of `$flag` can be[en, th, kh, ch] and all the extensions are my suffixes in table field.

```
$lang = $this->session->userdata('lang');
$query_id = $this->db->query("SELECT id, title_".$lang.", url, menu_parent FROM tbl_menu WHERE mainmenu_id='$mainmenu_id'");
```

Comment: So, what problem are you facing?

Comment: $flag value? Do you really store the the title in 4 different translations, in 4 fields? title_en, title_th, title_kh, title_ch

Comment: @Imran I can not use variable in sql

Comment: @Imran I try to use like this but not work title_".$lang."

Comment: @BrettSantore Yes

Comment: `var_dump($lang);` show something?

Comment: I don't why you are not using Active Record Query for this. Things very simple when you do it.

Comment: Now it work everyone the same script problem is my session don't start but I still have problem $row->title_."$lang" I can't do like this what I want is $row->title_en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use active record

```
$this->db->select('SELECT id, title_'.$lang.', url, menu_parent');
$this->db->from('tbl_menu');
$this->db->where('mainmenu_id', $mainmenu_id);
$res = $this->db->get()->result();
```